# Is it possible to generate SOAP message from XSD file?

Tags: soap, xsd

Is it possible to generate programmatically SOAP message from XSD file and if so how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Of course I've researched but nothing found. That's why I'm asking here. Maybe somebody had the same issue.

Comment: Since one of the key words here is "programatically" it would help if you could indicate what programming languages, or automation API (tool/product) you had in mind...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, this fell through the cracks... Below is one possible way of doing it.

The setup consists of two main components:

- Aquiring of an XML document based on the XSD
- Generation of the SOAP envelope and any other SOAP headers you may wish to add.

Creation of the XML may vary, based on more specific requirements; it can range from creating samples as described by this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx), to Excel spreadsheets, databases, etc.

To create the SOAP Envelope, all you need is one of the [System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createmessage.aspx) methods.